# Malicious javascript code in querystring for my website in google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, spam

In the google analytics report, I am seeing a lot of page views with the following javascript code added in the query string. Is someone trying to do something malicious to my website.

```
www.mywebsite.com/?constructor.prototype.protossbb=bountyplz
www.mywebsite.com/?__proto__.protossbb=bountyplz
www.mywebsite.com/?__proto__[protossbb]=bountyplz
www.mywebsite.com/?constructor[prototype][protossbb]=bountyplz
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone *is* trying to do something malicious. There's no reason to believe that they're succeeding, though. They [appear to be automatically trying attacks like that](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22protossbb%22) across many websites, in the hopes that it will happen to succeed on one of them. Prototype pollution is a fairly common vulnerability in JavaScript, so they are probably hoping that they will happen to find such a vulnerability by chance.

If you want to be sure you're okay, you can go to those URIs and make sure that nothing bad happens.